# Osmdroid offline data limit - GEMF as a solution?

Tags: android, zip, limit, osmdroid, large-data

I have been using osmdroid and offline ZIP Mapnik files. I have discovered, that into zip file, I can store no more then 65536 tiles. I have also noticed some information about GEMF file, which can handle large datasets. Is it cappable to replace ZIP file in Osmdroid? Does anyone have any experiences in building GEMF file and how to set Osmdroid to use GEMF files instead of ZIP?

**Edit:**

I have tried to run python code as seen here on my structure Mapnik/zoom/x/y.png, but I am getting bunch of errors. E.g.:

> File "generate_efficient_map_file.py", line 6   file_size_limit =
>   2000000000L

I have this file in the same folder, where is Mapnik folder located. What am I doing wroing?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Good news and bad news on this subject I think.

Using the very latest MOBAC version I set it up to produce an OsmdroidGEMF atlas and selected a fairly small area down to zoom level 15 (of 17). The resultant GEMF file was only about 5MB in size. I uplodaed just the GEMF file into the Osmdroid directory on my phone, which has my own Osmdroid (version 3.0.5) compatible app on it. I put the phone into Airplane mode and set the app into scroll mode (i.e. GPS off, so don't follow position) and scrolled to the area in question (where I've never been before, hence no cached tiles).

I worked OK down to level 14 zoom and the at level 15 every alternate tile looked like:

[image]

So, if you can find another way of generating the GEMFs, it requires no coding changes, just drop the files into the same folder you would use for the zips. (Presumably generating the zips by MOBAC is also now restricted too.)

Comment: I have my tiles from other sources, I just need to generate from my tiles structure: Mapnik/zoom/x/y.png generate GEMF file. I have tried python code generate_efficient_map_file.py as seen on: http://www.cgtk.co.uk/data/gemf/generate_efficient_map_file.py but I am getting bunch of errors, so I am wondering, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you with that as I have no knowledge of the subject. I wish you luck though.

Comment: With MOAB is there any differens if you throttle back it's fetch rate?

Comment: If you mean MOBAC, then I don't think so. I only asked for 5MB of data which just about covered the city of Perth (Scotland) down to a level where even the street names weren't shown. I'm not sure how you would throttle the rate or lower the active threads.

Comment: @NickT so which one works faster GEMF or ZIP? Please see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653043/android-load-offline-maptiles-in-the-background